# Python urllib.unquote_plus node.js equivalent

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, encoding, urllib

I'm trying to decode some data given through HTTP GET, basically something coming encoded by Python and I'm trying to decode it using Node.

**Python**:

```
data = "0%0E%09-%FB%CD%989%2B%C0%E5%A2+%28%93%D9%C9%86r0%9C%8D+%F1%E3v%0C%9E%19%91%E3%06%01%FA%D5%5B%F3%3D7%10%23%E7%95S%B7%93%60%DB%1F%1F%8A%E3%5D%CC%95%B8%DA%DB%A3%18%9FoVzC%23%FCB%8D%86%86N9%BE%AE%98%13x%0D%D9u%C48%F6%AD%A3%19z%BE%DB%8E-%C4T%02P%06%D5%C1%21%1F%FB%9C%EB%0A%7C%F9XFB%9D%F3"
print urllib.unquote_plus(data)
```

Output:

```
0   -�͘9+�� (��Ɇr0�� ��v
�u�8�z�ێ-�TP��!��          �����[�=7#�S��`���]̕��ۣ�oVzC#�B���N9���x
|�XFB��
```

---

**Node**:

```
var token = '0%0E%09-%FB%CD%989%2B%C0%E5%A2+%28%93%D9%C9%86r0%9C%8D+%F1%E3v%0C%9E%19%91%E3%06%01%FA%D5%5B%F3%3D7%10%23%E7%95S%B7%93%60%DB%1F%1F%8A%E3%5D%CC%95%B8%DA%DB%A3%18%9FoVzC%23%FCB%8D%86%86N9%BE%AE%98%13x%0D%D9u%C48%F6%AD%A3%19z%BE%DB%8E-%C4T%02P%06%D5%C1%21%1F%FB%9C%EB%0A%7C%F9XFB%9D%F3';
console.log(unescape(_.replace(token, '+', '%20')))
```

> `_` is Lodash library. See https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#replace

Output:

```
0   -ûÍ9+Àå¢ (ÙÉr0+ñãv
ÙuÄ8ö­£z¾Û-ÄTPÕÁ!ûë          ãúÕ[ó=7#çS·`Ûã]Ì¸ÚÛ£oVzC#üBN9¾®x
|ùXFBó
```

The two decoded outputs looks similar, but yet are a bit different and I can't figure why. Once decrypted (through another algorithm), they give a similar result, but the JS version has unexpected characters like `{"duration": 600m�B�}PO�UQ��:...}'` and I can't figure what's wrong with the JS implementation.

Comment: The python data already looks broken. What is that supposed to represent? The �͘ indicates charset decoding errors, therefore it can hardly be a desired result. Also, the JS `unescape()` function has been deprecated for many years, don't use it for anything.

Comment: It looks broken because it is a string encrypted using AES 256 CBC, using a padding. But it's just (as far as I understand) because the result is binary data, which is then encoded using `quote_plus`. When I decode and decrypt this string using Python, it works fine. But the decoded value looks weird indeed.

Comment: Ah, I see. An arbitrary binary value decoded as string would look like that.

Comment: By the way, ususally one would use Base64 to transport binary data in string form. Encoding it directly into percent encoding is not ideal. If you can, reconsider the value encoding approach.

Comment: Not my call, it's a customer's implementation. But duly noted, thanks ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the bounty! Very much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, you came up with a smart solution, and took the time to improve it to make it better, plus you helped me understand layers about cryptography I didn't get before. Your help was very much appreciated too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has been done before (it probably has, maybe I did not search properly).

What you seem to need is a function that decodes a string with percent encoding into a buffer of bytes, instead of into a string, as regular URL-decoding functions would try to do.

```
function bufferUrlDecode(data) {
    var buf = new Buffer(data, 'ascii');
    var pos = 0, flag = false, prev = null, i, b;

    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        b = buf[i];
        if (flag) {
            b -= b < 58 ? 48 : b < 97 ? 55 : 87;  // hex char to half-byte value
            if (b < 0 || b > 15) {
                throw new Error('invalid encoding at position ' + i);
            } else if (prev === null) {
                prev = b << 4;
            } else {
                buf[pos++] = prev + b;
                flag = false;
                prev = null;
            }
        } else {
            if (b === 43 /* '+' becomes space */) {
                buf[pos++] = 32;
            } else if (b === 37 /* '%' triggers URL decoding */) {
                flag = true;
            } else {
                buf[pos++] = b;
            }
        }
    }

    if (prev !== null) throw new Error('invalid encoding at position ' + data.length);
    return buf.slice(0, pos);
}
```

usage:

```
var str = "0%0E%09-%FB%CD%989%2B%C0%E5%A2+%28%93%D9%C9%86r0%9C%8D+%F1%E3v%0C%9E%19%91%E3%06%01%FA%D5%5B%F3%3D7%10%23%E7%95S%B7%93%60%DB%1F%1F%8A%E3%5D%CC%95%B8%DA%DB%A3%18%9FoVzC%23%FCB%8D%86%86N9%BE%AE%98%13x%0D%D9u%C48%F6%AD%A3%19z%BE%DB%8E-%C4T%02P%06%D5%C1%21%1F%FB%9C%EB%0A%7C%F9XFB%9D%F3";    
var bytes = bufferUrlDecode(str);
console.log(bytes);
console.log(bytes.toString('hex'));
```

output:

```
<Buffer 30 0e 09 2d fb cd 98 39 2b c0 e5 a2 20 28 ... >
300e092dfbcd98392bc0e5a22028 etc...
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna work in my use case, because the Buffer won't be usable by the decrypt AES-256-CBC algorithm (even as a string). I currently get `Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length` when I try it. What I'm looking for is the proper implementation of `urrllib.unquote_plus` in node. I tried mixing `unescape` and `replace` but I'm missing something.

Comment: Hm. The methods inside the `crypto` module work with Buffers, so I'm not sure what you mean by "Buffer won't be usable"? There was a stupid mistake in my implementation. Try again.

Comment: @Vadorequest My function provides correct output. Is there no feedback that you are able to give?

Comment: I was about to give it another try. I'll give you a feedback :)

Comment: In my case, I had to convert to `binary` instead of `hex`. But it works fine so far, I'll make more tests. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO you should not need to convert it in any way, all the node crypto functions take buffers for input (which one are you using?). The `hex` was just for the sake of human-readable console output.

Comment: Works like a charm, gonna give you a bounty, I wanted to make one anyway. I've been struggling with this for too long! Cheers :)

Comment: I'm posting a more optimized function in a second, I don't really like the `temp` string building bit and I'm going to replace it.

Comment: You're actually right. I thought I **had to** use binary, but that's only because my implementation of AES decrypt is using binary as input, that's all. I just figured that out. I'm not so experienced about encryption of sorts. I'm gonna use HEX for the sake of readability from now on. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Vadorequest I've made an improved version that runs a significantly faster (one order of magnitude) and has error checking.